# Multi-tenant schema with SLINGR

Tags: slingr

I'm developing an app using the low code platform SLINGR. I need to set permissions by the company an user belongs to.

What would be the best approach to implement this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is by using permissions with a filter of type `By user field`. For example, you can create an entity called `people` with the following structure:

```
- user
- company
```

Then, in `Application > Settings` in the app builder, you have to configure this entity as the one used for extended fields (https://slingr-stack.github.io/platform/app_development_app_settings.html#user-extended-fields). Once you do that, you will be able to filter by the company of the current user. For example, let's suppose you have an entity called `tasks` with the following structure:

```
- number
- title
- company
- description
```

Then, in the permissions for this entity, you will add a filter by user field where the field `tasks.company` is equals to `people.company`. This way, users will only see tasks that belong to the company they also belong to.